# How to change fill color of a cell in MS Excel 2010?

Tags: excel

i need to change color of a cell in excel 2010 by function.
a person who has low score be "Red" for example.

Comment: Try googling "Excel conditional formatting" and you'll see that it's designed to do exactly what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the steps to use **conditional formatting** (using Excel 2007/2010):

- Select the cells you want to apply the formatting to
- Click on Conditional Formatting on the ribbon
- Go to Highlight Cell Rules
- Select "Less than..."
- Enter the number you want and choose a 'fill' you want

**Hint**: Don't highlight the entire column of cells and apply the conditional formatting to it - it will hurt performance. Just highlight the cells you really need to apply it to.